# JFrame - reading two keystrokes (ESC and F2) and executing different actions

Tags: java, swing, focus, jframe, key-bindings

I'm looking to recognise two keystrokes from the ESC and F2 key. Below is how I recognise when the escape key is pressed:

```
// Enable escape to close the window by first returning the rootPane object for this frame, then the InputMap that is usedduring condition i.e. JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
    // and then use function put to add a binding for keyStroke to actionMapKey
    frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent. WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "Cancel");

    // Kill the AuotIt script when closing the window by first returning the rootPane object for this frame then the ActionMap used to determine what Action 
    // to fire for particular KeyStroke binding. The returned ActionMap, unless otherwise set, will have the ActionMap from the UI set as the parent.
    frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("Cancel", new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) {
            // Undertake some action here
        }
    });
```

I attempted the exact same thing but changing the keyevent to F2 but nothing happens when I press the F2 button. Below is how I attempted recognising the F2:

```
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), "pressed");

    // 
    frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("pressed", new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) {

            // Change the hasusersetcomport flag in hasusersetcomport.txt to 0
            notifyScriptThatUserNeedsCOMPorts("0");

            // Notify Script That User Pressed Allow Pairing (which is the default setting for wasallowpairingpressed.txt) 
            notifyScriptThatUserPressedAllowPairing("1");

            // Write menu Item Event Control ID
            RFC95.writeMenuItemEventControlID("8");

            // Write empty string into config file
            writeUserSelectedCOMportIntoConfigFile("");

            // Notify user that current pairing has been deleted
            notifMssgLabel.setText("<html><p>CURRENT PAIRING SETTING DELETED. WINDOW CLOSING</p></html>");
            notifMssgLabel.setForeground(officialSuccessFontColour);
            notifMssgLabel.setFont(officialFontBold);

            // Change the hasusersetcomport flag in hasusersetcomport.txt to 0
            notifyScriptThatUserNeedsCOMPorts("0");

            panelTimer.start();
        }
    });
```

Any ideas as to why I'm encountering the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the second action commented out?

Comment: What tbodt said. And, are you sure JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED is the correct focus situation ?

Comment: Hi all, sorry the second action being commented out was an error.

Comment: I attempted using the JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED with the second action and it didnt work

Comment: `I attempted using the JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED with the second action and it didnt work` - I think the suggestion was to use WHEN_FOCUSED_IN_WINDOW since that is what you used for the escape key and that worked. Also you should be aware that if other components use F2 they will have first priority. Post your `SSCCE` the demonstrates the problem if you need more help.